# Como adicionar suporte a customElements para Opera 12?

Tags: javascript, html5, polymer, x-tags, customelements

Estou trabalhando com customElements, porém venho tendo problema com o Opera 12.

Até agora o melhor que consegui foi utilizar o [x-tags](http://www.x-tags.org/) porém o mesmo da suporte apenas ao `document.register` e este se diferencia um pouco da [API proposta pela W3C](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/), outro inconveniente é que ele não da suporte ao `document.registerElement`.

Continuando minhas pesquisas eu achei o [Polymer-project](http://www.polymer-project.org/) que é bastante promissor e no Webkit funcionou muito bem, porém no Opera, quando executado o `plataform.js` do Polymer, este faz com que os scripts subsequentes comecem a dar erros, fazendo parar por exemplo conexão com websocket e sequer consegue executar o `polymer.js` para adicionar suporte a customElements.

De base dessas informações, gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar com uma solução consistente para Opera, que não quebre as implementações nativas do mesmo e de suporte a `document.registerElement` mais próximo possível da API em draft da W3C.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Após muito pesquisar sobre o assunto, descobri que existe um polyfill que foi feito pela equipe do Polymer, que é independente do `plataform.js` e adiciona suporte aos browsers modernos a Custom Elements de forma bem completa.

https://github.com/Polymer/CustomElements

Fiz testes com essa lib independente do Polymer com o Opera 12 e obtive sucesso ao utilizar os métodos `document.register` e `document.registerElement` com todos recursos documentados no W3C draft atual.

Só pra resalvar, esta lib adiciona apenas os recursos necessários para Custom Elements. HTMLImport, Object.observer e outros recursos usados no Polymer terão de ser carregados separadamente se for de desejo utiliza-los.