# Para que server a propriedade "customElements"?

Tags: javascript

Navegando aqui no **SOpt** encontrei a seguinte pergunta: [**Como adicionar suporte a customElements para Opera 12?**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/3384), e gostaria de saber qual a utilidade dessa propriedade.

Note que fazendo uma simples [**pesquisa**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+customElements) por aqui, até esta data só existe essa pergunta citada.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traduzindo de uma forma bem simples, `customElements` significa **elementos customizados**. Isso quer dizer que você pode criar o seu próprio elemento, assim como você pode usar os elementos `<a> <br> <div>`.

Para poder usar esta propriedade, o navegador precisa implementar a especificação [Custom Elements v1](https://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/). Nela também estão especificadas as regras que os desenvolvedores precisam seguir para implementar seus elementos customizados.

Para começar a entender o seu uso, eu sugiro usar os [tutoriais do Google](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-components/customelements), é bem mais fácil de entender do que a especificação.

Por exemplo:

```js
class WmSouza extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.appendChild(document.createTextNode(" especial para wmsouza"));
  }
}
window.customElements.define('wm-souza', WmSouza);
```

```html
<wm-souza>teste</wm-souza>
```

Comment: Tive o mesmo problema e funcionou pra mim. Valeu! :)

Answer (score 2):

"Custom Elements” é uma especificação de componente web que define como criar e usar novos tipos de elementos DOM. Existem algumas regras básicas sobre como nomear e definir seus elementos personalizados. Eles são:

- O nome do seu elemento personalizado deve conter um dash (-) . Por exemplo,`<file-reader>` e `<skype-login>` são nomes válidos para elementos personalizados, enquanto `<skype_login>` e `<skypelogin>` não são. Isso é necessário para permitir que o analisador HTML diferencia um elemento personalizado e um elemento HTML incorporado.
- Um elemento personalizado não pode ser registrado mais de uma vez. Um `DOMException` erro será lançado se você fizer isso.
- Um elemento personalizado não pode ser auto-fechado. Por exemplo, você não pode escrever um elemento personalizado como este: `<skype-login />`.Ele sempre deve ser escrito assim: `<skype-login></skype-login>`.

Um elemento personalizado pode ser criado usando o `customElements.define()` método da API do navegador e uma classe que se estende `HTMLElement` em JavaScript, assim:

```js
class ErickPrates extends HTMLElement {
  // Definir comportamento aqui
}

window.customElements.define('Erick-Prates', ErickPrates);
```

Outra opção é usar uma classe anônima assim:

```js
window.customElements.define('Erick-Prates', class extends HTMLElement {
  // Definir comportamento aqui
});
```

Com isso já definido, agora você pode usar o elemento personalizado em uma página da Web, assim:

```js
<Erick-Prates></Erick-Prates>
```

Você pode definir propriedades em um CustomElement. Por exemplo, vamos adicionar um atributo chamado `open` e ao nosso `<Erick-Prates>` elemento. Isso pode ser alcançado assim:

```js
class ErickPrates extends HTMLElement {
  // Defina a propriedade "open"
  set open(option) {
    this.setAttribute("open", option);
  }

  // Obter a propriedade "open"
  get open() {
    return this.hasAttribute("open");
  }

}
```

> isso se refere ao próprio elemento DOM. Então, neste exemplo, isso se refere `<Erick-Prates>`.

Depois de ter feito isso, agora você pode usar o elemento personalizado em seu navegador como este:

```js
<Erick-Prates open="true"></Erick-Prates>
```

Você também pode definir um construtor na classe, mas você deve chamar o `super()` método antes de adicionar qualquer outro código.

Existem ganchos do ciclo de vida que os elementos personalizados podem definir durante sua existência. Esses ganchos são:

- **construtor ()**: Aqui, você pode anexar ouvintes de eventos e inicializar o estado.
- **connectedCallback ()**: Chamado sempre que o elemento personalizado é inserido no DOM.
- **desconectadoCallback ()**: Chamado sempre que o elemento personalizado é removido do DOM.
- **attributeChangedCallback (attrName, oldVal, newVal)**: Chamado sempre que um atributo é adicionado, removido ou atualizado. Apenas os atributos listados na propriedade **observadaAttributes** são afetados.
- **adoptadoCallback ()**: Chamado sempre que o elemento personalizado foi movido para um novo documento.

Você pode fazer referência à [especificação de elemento personalizado](http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/) para obter mais informações.